# How can I make whole document in italics

Tags: formatting

I need to make whole document in italics. May be with few sections in normal font. How to configure the preamble for such thing? I don't want every line/paragraph include in `\textit` or `\emph`.

Comment: `\itshape` should do

Comment: But, please don't!

Comment: To reinforce @kan 's plea, having to read italic text in bulk is generally considered to be extremely tiring.

Comment: If you do this your document will look like <anagram of @ChristianHupfer's suggestion 3,4>

Comment: @IanThompson: I did not say, that the document would look good. I dislike italic text in general.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer --- I didn't mean to imply you did. I just noticed a good anagram of `itshape`.

Comment: @IanThompson: :D

Comment: Thanks, \itshape is what I need. I know this is ugly but documentation for my course project must be in Arial 14 italics. I did it in Libreoffice for reassurance and now learning latex trying to re-create documentation with it.

Comment: My condolences.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, as stated by Christian, you may go with `\itshape` just right after `\begin{document}` to get **all** your document in italics.

However, as stated by Kan, this looks awful, and should be avoided at all costs.  Italics are used to *emphasize* or when you have a foreign word in your text, such as *esta*.

What I think you might be looking for (or at least, might be helpful) would be a light font.  Now, I cannot tell you which one (since it will depend on your document type, what you are writing, your aesthetics, etc.) but I can tell you where to find a huge catalog with lots of them:  The [LaTeX Font Catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/)

Examples of what I'm talking about:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{chancery}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}
\kant
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Local font selection`

```
{
\fontencoding{T1}\fontfamily{anttlc}\fontseries{m}\fontshape{n}\selectfont
Some text in anttlc...
}
```

and define italic font for some area of your text like below

```
\begin{document}

\section{Before you start}

{ % BEGINING OF AREA
\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{it}
Here is my italic area
} % END OF AREA

And here is my non italic area

\end{document}
```

[image]

You Can read more about Fonts from this link [LaTeX/Font - Wkibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Fonts)